# flask-sqlalchemy model property to string

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)

    def id_to_string(self):
        return str(id)
```

but when I call the Product.id_to_string() function, it gives me:

```
<built-in function id>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the value of the id as a string?

Comment: `id` is an attribute on the model instance. So you need to refer to it as `self.id`.

Comment: of course, I don't know how I missed that :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a `self` modifier within your function:

```
def id_to_string(self):
  return str(self.id)
```

otherwise you'll call the `id` built-in (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).) This is why most linters will actually flag you for using "id" as a variable name, even if it makes sense.

Comment: Oh my god I feel so stupid now :( Thank you very much!

Comment: @NiniMichaels Really? I'd feel much dumber if I didn't ask this type of question and instead waste hours scratching my head. That's why a second set of eyes is so good to have. Kudos to you for actually asking. Many people would be too ashamed (and thus slow down or stop their learning.)

Answer (score 1):

```
@property
def id_to_string(self):
  return str(self.id)
```

You can also use a decorator if you want.